# Xamarin Forms ENOENT (No such file or directory) on API 23

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am using the following code to download and open files from a stream in my Xamarin Forms Android Project. This is working in all APIs < 23.

In API 23 I get the following exception on the line: FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

{Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/pgmdoc/myiamge.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) ---> Android.Systems.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SaveAndLoad_Android))]
namespace MyProgram.Droid
{
public class SaveAndLoad_Android : MYProgramFiles.ISaveAndLoad
    {
        public async Task SaveFileAsync(string fileName, String contentType, MemoryStream stream)
        {
            string root = null;
            if (Android.OS.Environment.IsExternalStorageEmulated)
            {
                root = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString();
            }
            else
                root = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

            Java.IO.File myDir = new Java.IO.File(root + "/pgmdoc");
            if (!myDir.Exists())
            {
                myDir.Mkdir();
            }

            Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(myDir, fileName);


            try
            {
                FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                outStream.Write(stream.ToArray());
                outStream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //error happenin on
                //FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            }
            if (file.Exists())
            {
                Android.Net.Uri path = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
                string extension = Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(path.ToString());
                string mimeType = Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                intent.SetDataAndType(path, mimeType);
                Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select App"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my Android Manafest I have specified the permissions:
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE 
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Any Help is Appreciated

Comment: For API 23+ you need to specify run-time permissions in your app if you require a [dangerous](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#perm-groups) permission such as storage in your app.

Comment: Thanks.  That was it.

Answer (score 0):

Pztar was correct.

There is a useful sample here for those in need: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android-m/RuntimePermissions/

And if you are using a dependency service, I highly suggest the current activity plugin and the permissions plugin.

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin